# Unity 2017.1.1f Tilemap pallet disappeared

Tags: unity-game-engine

My Unity tilemap pallet disappeared and when go to window tap it's not there how can i find the pallet and another thing is, when i want to make new pallet from component > 2d object> there is no tilemap and just sprite and ...
My unity version is 2017.1.1f.

Comment: isn't tilemap 2017.2 thing?